# Laravel 5.3 integrate dingo api and oauth2 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause'

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, dingo-api

I'm using laravel 5.3 to build api and backend management for mobile app.
I'm integrated Dingo/api package and use Oauth2 for authenticate.
I made an API and login with postman: 
API url: mydomain/api/auth/login
Logged in result:

> {
>     "meta": {
>       "message": "Success",
>       "status_code": 1000,
>       "status": true
>     },
>     "data": {
>       "access_token": "BK81coQ8mnR7PrfEuYzOwKBuZukXgeVw2pcUjHcZ",
>       "token_type": "Bearer",
>       "expires_in": 604800,
>       "refresh_token": "KRIB6YnvqT25rG1fGtoMrK9mGeB7m2J3cdj9QB8N",
>       "profile": {
>         "id": 1,
>         "user_id": 1,
>         "name": "ThanhDN",
>         "postal_code": null,
>         "phone_number": null,
>         "age": null,
>         "gender": null,
>         "address": null,
>         "avatar": null,
>         "status": null,
>         "created_at": "2017-01-11 04:44:33",
>         "updated_at": "2017-01-11 04:44:33",
>         "deleted_at": null
>       }
>     }
>   }

I used access_token to call API for get user information
API url: mydomain/api/user/1
But I got an error:

> {"message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = 9mQmZqIjqnRamzX7syjtU6X1jGWrfQXndKKT97TU limit 1)","code":"42S22","status_code":500,

I've searched but could not see any solution. Please help me resolve it.
Thank you very much!!!

And even when you call logout 
url: mydomain/api/logout

Answer (score 31):

Make sure you have `['guards']['api']['driver']` set to `passport` in `config/auth.php`, and updated the configuration cache: `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, thank you daddy, just clearing of cache I needed. Spent over an house wondering what the heck i had done wrong. God bless you!!! +1

Comment: VERY NICEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

Answer (score 0):

First of all run this command to refresh all the database migrations

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

and, after, run this command

```
php artisan passport:install
```